# Paste from the clipboard history shortcut not working in qt creator

Tags: qt-creator

I'm reading *Qt Creator Manual* and found Qt creator provides short cut (Ctrl+Shift+V) for paste from the clipboard history.

I'm currently using Qt Creator 2.4.1 and tried hard to press **Ctrl+Shift+V**, but nothing happened.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works great for me in `QtCreator 3.3.1` you need to copy some text and when you hit `Ctrl+Shift+V` opens a windows and you can select your clipboard.

[image]

**UPDATE**

this shortcut seen for first time in Qt Creator 2.6 reference card. you can find it in [here](http://www.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/stories/QtCreator-2.6.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. Is this feature not in the versions before 3.3.1?